# Need a delay in my MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

I want a client connection to wait for some data that may come 3 or 4 seconds later.

The idea was to make a Thread.sleep and recheck some times but I don't want to stuck other clients because some clients won't have to wait but some do.

I'm new to MVC and hope that you can give me some suggestions.

/edit
If I use this code:

```
    public string weatherAsync(string city)
    {
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Increment();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        AsyncManager.Parameters["output"] = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString();
        AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations.Decrement();
    });

        return null;
    }

    public string weatherCompleted(string output)
    {
        return output;
    }
```

And request my page two times at the same time the first one returns the time after about 10 seconds and AFTER that the second page  need 10 more seconds to return the output :-/

Is this a problem of my controller or Thread.sleep?

Comment: how do you get your data ? some code will be helpful.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` is a big no-no in ASP.NET, think about AJAX or SignalR

Comment: Delaying the actual response for so long is a bad idea. You will have to split your Action, probably using Ajax for the 2nd part.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good architecture. You shouldn't ever just be waiting for data at this level; use a callback or async workflow, sending data to the client when ready. Or even load the page first and lazy load the rest with AJAX.

Comment: Okay here is what I want at all: I want to give my mobile apps an API to receive weather informations for their city. Because I want to limit the requests to the weatherservice-api I want to store the data in my own database. If a requested data is too old I want to update it for my database.. now if one update is in process I want the other requests (for the same city) to wait until the first thread for their city has finished updating the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thread.Sleep will not block other users but it will block current thread so it cannot be reused by other clients.

If you are doing call to some external web service in your controller please take a look on asyncronous APi in ASP.NET MVC [Asyncronous Methods In ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4).

Comment: I don't think that this will be enough for a 3-4 sec delay.